# Alternative to DBs for storing audit logs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, audit-logging

I'm currently developing a system that is used for generating verification codes. The system authenticates a user, sends them a code, stores it locally, then at some later point receives the code from the user, after which point the code is spent and deleted from the system

The original proposal was to create this system using an SQL database, however this use case just screams Kafka, and since these codes have a very short duration (they expire in 30 seconds, which means that they must be spent almost immediately) it only makes sense to have producers and consumers that create and consume events that hold these codes.

However, the issue is that all events must be logged, i.e. upon code consumption/expiration something must be written in the audit log. Also, any attempt to use an invalid code must be logged as well. It seems like a waste to have a fully fledged database and then use it to have one AUDIT_LOG table in it.

Since we're using Spring boot we'd like to use some plug-and-play solution that can be easily interfaced with. I've seen suggestions of using Kafka itself to store audit logs, but we need long term persistence and Kafka doesn't seem ideal for that. Using a no-SQL DBs was also suggested, and I've seen some promising append-only solutions.

Do you folks have anything to recommend here?

Comment: the db choice totally depends on for how long you need to store these logs and size of audit log record. if its very simple structure then you can go with sql , if its complex json like structure go with no-sql obviously but choice of DB is again depends on cost that you want to spend and how important these audit logs are.

you can also dump these audit logs to some file system , compress it at end of day and upload it to some cold storage like S3 or Azur Blob

Comment: @prasannajoshi

The thing is that I'm looking for a way to sidestep the need for a database entirely. S3 and Azur Blob sound nice, I would however prefer an offline solution that is stored locally.

Comment: so you can just compress them and store it in some local storage as well but question is who is going to review/use these audit logs and whether they will need any interface/UI or some tool to view it ? based on these questions your storage requirement will changes and also it depends where your server is sitting ?  on cloud or some on-prim/dedicated cluster and if it can connect to any local storage seamlessly ...

Comment: @prasannajoshi The service will be running on our machines, this is what I mean by "local". So ideally it is some small DB-like system that doesn't offer the full functionality of SQL and no-SQL databases but is good enough for storing simple audit logs, and doesn't come with overhead and maintenance costs of traditional databases. 

Due to relative simplicity of this data I would assume that querying it and getting data back in say json format would be readable enough. I also assume that it is possible to export it to txt/xls.

Comment: not sure if its local then are you even care much , just dump to any file format and use editor or ms office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> original proposal was to create this system using an SQL database

Use both? Kafka Connect can write to JDBC databases from Kafka topics. This way, you don't need to write JDBC Clients within your Java code, and non-Java clients can also send data to the same Kafka topic since the protocol is generic TCP, not specific to your database.

If that SQL database doesn't work, you can still consume the same Kafka topic to a different system (Elasticsearch works great for log analysis, as does HDFS or S3 for larger datasets). Since you mention "offline" systems, then MinIO is a self-hosted, S3 compatible option.

Comment: Using both is also an option.

Elasticsearch sounds like it might be the perfect solution here actually, funny that I didn't think of it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to it's [home page](https://kafka.apache.org) kafka is for

> data pipelines, streaming analytics, data integration, and mission-critical applications

But you stated that an important functionality of your application is persistent storage of structured data. So it's highly doubtable whether kafka is a good long term fit for this purpose if that purpose isn't advocated by kafka itself.

Also keep in mind that there is probably more to your application than just the use cases. Maybe at some point reporting functionality is required. Than you are probably way better of leveraging a reporting product that probably a lot of people already know or have worked with than reinventing all of that on top of kafka (even though streaming analytics is a use case for kafka, but it probably is way lesser known than for example an sql reporting tool).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, audit logs must be persisted, data that is required for the application to run has a lifetime measured in seconds. I did point out that Kafka isn't a perfect solution for storing audit logs in a persistent way. 

It is highly unlikely that any additional functionality will be added on top.

Comment: @MrLinjak You can write Kafka logs to S3/Azure/HDFS. Kafka was originally created with this exact use case (for Hadoop, specifically)